# Team project doesn't build because of missing reference to ajax control toolkit

Tags: tfsbuild

I started exploring the build services of Team Foundation Server 2010. I set up Build Controller and Agent on my Team Foundation Server, and a shared folder for the builds.

However, every time I try to queu a build of my team project, I get an error saying:

The type or namespace name 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I don't know what to do with this error. Before I start using TFS Build Services, I didn't get this error.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Anthony
Belgium

Answer (score 0):

Build server do what you do on your machine, so if you required third party library that's meaning your build server will required this library too, in other words you have to install all the library that you use on your local machine on the build server, so just put the Ajax tool kit in the build server

Thanks
M.Radwan

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, much appreciated. I put the ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll in the target folder (Builds/1/application/binaries ) but this is not working. I still get this error message:

Admin\Dossiers.aspx.designer.cs (22): The type or namespace name 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I'm not quite sure if I completely understand your advice to put the .dll on the build server. Do you mean by this to put the .dll in the Build folder on the build server?

Thanks for your help,
Anthony